# parsing HTML text in local XML file in android

Tags: android, html, xml

I am trying to parse an local xml file in the android application, But some of the code is in HTML format stored in CDATA section in the xml tags. how can I get that data parsed as well??

Comment: I am using DOM Parser to parse XML file, Please tell how to parse HTML

Comment: I found the solution it is passing the CDATA section character string to the textview as


        textView.setText((Html.fromHtml(string),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

Comment: I found the solution it is passing the CDATA section character string to the textview as     textView.setText((Html.fromHtml(string),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution it is passing the CDATA section character string to the textview as

```
textView.setText((Html.fromHtml(string),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```